# JavaScript runtime error,jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript

When i add fullcalendar to my aspx portal,when run the visual studio 2010 show:

```
JavaScript runtime error,not define jQuery.
```

This is the portal.aspx code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../images/HomeImage/PicNews/calendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../images/HomeImage/PicNews/calendar/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <link href="../images/HomeImage/PicNews/calendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../images/HomeImage/PicNews/calendar/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../images/HomeImage/PicNews/calendar/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../images/HomeImage/PicNews/calendar/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../images/HomeImage/PicNews/calendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../images/HomeImage/PicNews/calendar/jquery.min.js">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                theme: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                editable: true,
                events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                    end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                    url: 'http://google.com/'
                }
            ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is where the error occour in js file:

```
(function($, undefined) {


;;

var defaults = {

    // display
    defaultView: 'month',
    aspectRatio: 1.35,
    header: {
        left: 'title',
        center: '',
        right: 'today prev,next'
    },
    weekends: true,
    weekNumbers: false,
    weekNumberCalculation: 'iso',
    weekNumberTitle: 'W',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to put the jquery reference before the calendar reference.  Since you're included it twice, just remove the first reference (the first line of your included code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../images/HomeImage/PicNews/calendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
```